# does this javascript fire when no result is returned from the database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code:

```
 $.post('get_as_12', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
 alert(result[0]) ;

      if(result[0] > 0) {
          $('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
          alert('12-1');
       } else {
          $('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');
          alert('12-2');
      }
 });
```

get_as_12 is a MySQL query.

the alert `alert(result[0]) ;` is fired correctly when there is a database result. if there however is no result and the returned value is `NULL` how do I get the alert to still fire. more than this, how do I get the else statement to fire:
`$('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');`

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
 $.post('get_as_12', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
 alert(result[0]) ;

      if(result[0].length > 0) {
          $('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
       } else {
          $('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$.post('get_as_12', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
    if(result != null && result[0] > 0) {
        $('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
        alert('12-1');
    } else {
        $('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');
        alert('12-2');
    }
});
```

That adds a check that result isn't `null` or `undefined`. If you're sure that a defined result will be an array with at least one element in it, that should be fine. Otherwise you need to add a check that `result.length > 0`

Comment: Thanks phenomnomnominal, as mentioned to the others, the if statement is not even running when the database result is NULL. how can we fix this line to execute even when result is null? `$.post('get_as_12', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {
`

Comment: Are you saying that when the database returns null, the function above doesn't fire at all? For instance, if you put `alert('hello');` on the first line of the function, does it work? If it doesn't work, you should try adding an `error` handler, which unfortunately means you need to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.post`, which has a slightly different way of being called. Alternatively, you could add a global [`ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) error function.

Comment: 100% correct. the alert('hello') does not fire when result in NULL. can you help with the global ajaxerror or the $.ajax, I am out of my depth here. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks phenomnomnominal, working perfectly after some tweeks my side. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the length of result[0]

```
if(result && result[0].length > 0) {.......
```

I'm assuming that result[0] contains an array with the result of your mysql query. With the length property, you can check whether your result set is empty, therefore it should call your statement else-statement if your query doesn't return results.

Comment: Thanks Sutuma, what you say makes sense. My problem though is that the function doesn't even fire if result is NULL. will update question with the new syntax now. thanks.

Comment: if you look at the updated question, the alert doesn't even fire, that's before `if(result && result[0].length > 0)` even runs? any ideas?

Comment: Ah gosh, sorry for being to fast with my answer. Your ajax request is simply failing. $.post takes an URL as the first argument, e.g. /your_script_that_fires_the_mysql_query.php. What is "get_as_12" exactly?

Comment: get_as_12 is a codeigniter controller function. basically a sql result. it returns a single row only. either result is a number or NULL. it is failing when NULL.. let me know if you want to see the code. Thakns again.

Comment: it works 100% when get_as_12 returns a number response. just failing when response is NULL. If it is null I need to uncheck the checkbox :-)

Comment: The first alert should fire if the request doesn't fail. Please check the request with firebug or chrome developer tools. What's the response of the request in the network tab?

Comment: Sutuma,playing with this some more, works 100% you legend! Thanks SO much.

Answer (score 0):

I expect when the server returns `null` response it is not being handled correctly by `$.post` to process the request.

You can try using `$.ajax` instead, as this allows for better error handling and processing.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get_as_12',
    data: {
        data:selectedObj.value
    },
    success: function(result){
        if(result != null && result[0] > 0) {
            $('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
            alert('12-1');
        } else {
            $('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');
            alert('12-2');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
        // or use alert to send user a message
    }
});
```

The key things to note here are the `success` and `error` handlers.  The `error` is triggered if the response is invalid or none is given by the server.

The code is untested; so changes may be required.

Comment: Tanks Kami, error with this is: `success: function(result){` any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: @Smudger @Phenomnomnominal made a correction to this.  There was an extra `}` in the `data` element.  Please remove it and try again.